# How do I find the complete list of url-paths within a website for scraping?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Is there a way I can use python to see the complete list of url-paths for a website I am scraping?

The structure of the url doesn't change just the paths:

```
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/{city}/guides/best-cafes-{area}
```

Right now I have a function that allows me to define `{city}` and `{area}` using an f-string literal but I have to do this manually. For example: `city = melbourne` and `area = fitzroy`.

I'd like to try and make the function iterate through all available paths for me but I need to work out how to get the complete list of paths.

Is there a way a scraper can do it?

Comment: give an example of the city and the area

Comment: thanks for the feedback added an example.

Comment: are there more cities than the five they list? Why not just use them as city? I.e. Sydney, Melbourne, Brisbane, Adelaide, Perth

Comment: Have you considered looking through the sitemaps? I think all the relevant urls are listed there. Starting from [here](https://www.broadsheet.com.au/sitemap), you can find everyting you need. If this is a one time thing, you could do it manually, otherwise you can try scraping the sitemaps for relevant links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the sitemap for the required URLs, for example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.broadsheet.com.au/sitemap'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for loc in soup.select('loc'):
    if not loc.text.strip().endswith('/guide'):
        continue
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(loc.text).content, 'html.parser')
    for loc2 in soup2.select('loc'):
        if '/best-cafes-' in loc2.text:
            print(loc2.text)
```

Prints:

```
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-st-kilda
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-fitzroy
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-balaclava
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-preston
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-seddon
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-northcote
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-fairfield
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-ascot-vale
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-west-melbourne
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-flemington
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-windsor
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-kensington
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-prahran
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-essendon
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-pascoe-vale
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-albert-park
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-port-melbourne
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-armadale
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-brighton
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-malvern
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-malvern-east
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-glen-iris
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-camberwell
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-hawthorn-east
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-brunswick-east
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-bentleigh
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-coburg
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-richmond
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-bentleigh-east
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-collingwood
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-elwood
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-abbotsford
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-south-yarra
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-yarraville
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-thornbury
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-west-footscray
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-footscray
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-south-melbourne
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-hawthorn
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-carlton-north
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-brunswick
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-carlton
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-elsternwick
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/sydney/guides/best-cafes-bronte
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/sydney/guides/best-cafes-coogee
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/sydney/guides/best-cafes-rosebery
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/sydney/guides/best-cafes-ultimo
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/sydney/guides/best-cafes-enmore
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/sydney/guides/best-cafes-dulwich-hill
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/sydney/guides/best-cafes-leichhardt
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/sydney/guides/best-cafes-glebe
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/sydney/guides/best-cafes-annandale
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/sydney/guides/best-cafes-rozelle
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/sydney/guides/best-cafes-paddington
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/sydney/guides/best-cafes-balmain
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/sydney/guides/best-cafes-erskineville
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/sydney/guides/best-cafes-willoughby
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/sydney/guides/best-cafes-bondi-junction
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/sydney/guides/best-cafes-north-sydney
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/sydney/guides/best-cafes-bondi
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/sydney/guides/best-cafes-potts-point
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/sydney/guides/best-cafes-mosman
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/sydney/guides/best-cafes-alexandria
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/sydney/guides/best-cafes-crows-nest
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/sydney/guides/best-cafes-manly
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/sydney/guides/best-cafes-woolloomooloo
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/sydney/guides/best-cafes-newtown
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/sydney/guides/best-cafes-vaucluse
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/sydney/guides/best-cafes-chippendale
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/sydney/guides/best-cafes-marrickville
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/sydney/guides/best-cafes-redfern
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/sydney/guides/best-cafes-camperdown
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/sydney/guides/best-cafes-darlinghurst
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/adelaide/guides/best-cafes-goodwood
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/perth/guides/best-cafes-northbridge
https://www.broadsheet.com.au/perth/guides/best-cafes-leederville
```

Comment: Thanks that's fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially trying to create a spider just like search engines do. So, why not use one that already exists? It's free up to 100 daily queries. You will have to set up a Google Custom Search and define a search query.

1. get your API key from here: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/introduction/?apix=true
2. define a new search engine: https://cse.google.com/cse/all using URL https://www.broadsheet.com.au/
3. Click `public URL` and copy the part from `cx=123456:abcdef`
4. place your API key and the cx-part in below URL `google`
5. adjust the below query to get the results for different cities. I set it up to find results for Melbourne but you can use a placeholder there easily and format the string.

```
import requests

google = 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key={your_custom_search_key}&cx={your_custom_search_id}&q=site:https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best+%22best+cafes+in%22+%22melbourne%22&start={}'

results = []
with requests.Session() as session:
    start = 1
    while True:
        result = session.get(google.format(start)).json()
        if 'nextPage' in result['queries'].keys():
            start = result['queries']['nextPage'][0]['startIndex']
            print(start)
        else:
            break
        results += result['items']
```